# How to pass a function as argument to a generated Happy parser?

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming, happy

Happy generates a parser with signature :: `[Token] -> a`

I would like to generate a parameterized parser, i.e., a function that needs a function as argument to deliver a parser.
So I would like the signature :: `(x->y) -> [Token] -> a`.
Yet, I can also work with the signature :: `[Token] -> (x->y) -> a`.

When the function is fixed, I can solve it 
by importing and assigning the function.

```
import Functions (fixedFunction)

Root : Production Rule
       { $$.argument = fixedFunction
       }
```

When the argument is an instance of Show, I can solve it as follows

```
Alex:
   data Token = ...
              |  Carg            ArgType
Happy:
    %token 
        ...
        Argument { Carg $$ }

    Root : Argument Production Rule
           {  $$.argument = $1
           }
```

See e.g. my project TorXakis for more details, in particular the folder https://github.com/TorXakis/TorXakis/tree/develop/sys/front/src

However, I am unable to pass a variable argument that is a function since a function does not derive from Show!
Since Haskell is a functional language, I have the strong suspicion that I am missing something trivial, yet I don't see it...
Can anybody please provide an example of passing a function to a happy-generated parser?
Thanks in advance!

Pierre

Answer (score 2):

`happy` allows you to work over Monad. It can consume `lexer` functions with one of the next two signatures:

1. `[Token] -> a`
2. `Monad m => (Token -> m a) -> m a`

First option is context-free and second is context-aware. If you need to pass extra arguments to `lexer` function you can do one of two things:

1. Partially apply `lexer` to you function in `.y` file like this:

   `%lexer { lexer fixedFunction }`

   And your `lexer` function will have type `T -> [Token] -> a` where `T` is type of `fixedFunction`.
2. Pass function inside some context, like `Reader` monad. I used `State` monad to track token positions. You can see my examples here: [my monad](https://github.com/ChShersh/rogue-lang/blob/d8c44123d870fcf3472ce03c18473950378bc169/src/Rogue/Parser/ParserMonad.hs#L30) and [my lexer](https://github.com/ChShersh/rogue-lang/blob/d8c44123d870fcf3472ce03c18473950378bc169/src/Rogue/Parser/Lexer.hs#L22).

With any solution you can add extra arguments and some extra context to your `lexer`.

Comment: In your monadic parser you don't use attribute grammars as far as I can see. Do you know whether in Happy you can mix monadic parsers and attribute grammars?

Comment: @DamianNadales seems like it's possible. Only some syntactic difference in conditional rules: https://www.haskell.org/happy/doc/html/sec-AtrributeGrammarsInHappy.html I can't imagine reason why it shouldn't be possible to mix monadic parsers and attributes.

Comment: I asked because the use of monadic parser requires  a special syntax `{%...} ` and I don't know whether this can be done.

Comment: @DamianNadales I guess it's not a problem. Inside `{%...}` you can write any monadic actions within your monad. I didn't use attributes, I don't have much experience with them. But seems like it's possible. Just try to experiment. And if you stuck with some small example then you can ask specific question about those two.

Comment: I've tried mixing attribute grammars and monadic parsers and I failed so far. I guess there is a reason why the Haskell parser does not use attribute grammars: https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/compiler/parser/Parser.y

Answer (score 0):

This example is based on the standard happy example (
see e.g. https://www.haskell.org/happy/doc/html/sec-using.html)
This example uses no monads and no attributes.

The Expression parser needs a function to "standardize" the variable names.
For example, make them case insensitive or, like in old programming languages, consider only the first 8 characters.

The parser is:

```
{
module Calc
( calc
, lexer
)
where
import Data.Char
}
%name calc
%tokentype { Token }
%error { parseError }

%token 
      let             { TokenLet }
      in              { TokenIn }
      int             { TokenInt $$ }
      var             { TokenVar $$ }
      '='             { TokenEq }
      '+'             { TokenPlus }
      '-'             { TokenMinus }
      '*'             { TokenTimes }
      '/'             { TokenDiv }
      '('             { TokenOB }
      ')'             { TokenCB }

%%

Exp   :: { (String -> String) -> Exp } 
      : let var '=' Exp in Exp  { \p -> Let (p $2) ($4 p) ($6 p) }
      | Exp1                    { \p -> Exp1 ($1 p) }

Exp1  :: { (String -> String) -> Exp1 } 
      : Exp1 '+' Term           { \p -> Plus ($1 p) ($3 p) }
      | Exp1 '-' Term           { \p -> Minus ($1 p) ($3 p) }
      | Term                    { \p -> Term ($1 p) }

Term  :: { (String -> String) -> Term } 
      : Term '*' Factor         { \p -> Times ($1 p) ($3 p) }
      | Term '/' Factor         { \p -> Div ($1 p) ($3 p) }
      | Factor                  { \p -> Factor ($1 p) }

Factor:: { (String -> String) -> Factor }
      : int                     { \p -> Int $1 }
      | var                     { \p -> Var (p $1) }
      | '(' Exp ')'             { \p -> Brack ($2 p) }

{
parseError :: [Token] -> a
parseError _ = error "Parse error"

data Exp  
      = Let String Exp Exp
      | Exp1 Exp1
      deriving Show

data Exp1 
      = Plus Exp1 Term 
      | Minus Exp1 Term 
      | Term Term
      deriving Show

data Term 
      = Times Term Factor 
      | Div Term Factor 
      | Factor Factor
      deriving Show

data Factor 
      = Int Int 
      | Var String 
      | Brack Exp
      deriving Show

data Token
      = TokenLet
      | TokenIn
      | TokenInt Int
      | TokenVar String
      | TokenEq
      | TokenPlus
      | TokenMinus
      | TokenTimes
      | TokenDiv
      | TokenOB
      | TokenCB
 deriving Show


lexer :: String -> [Token]
lexer [] = []
lexer (c:cs) 
      | isSpace c = lexer cs
      | isAlpha c = lexVar (c:cs)
      | isDigit c = lexNum (c:cs)
lexer ('=':cs) = TokenEq : lexer cs
lexer ('+':cs) = TokenPlus : lexer cs
lexer ('-':cs) = TokenMinus : lexer cs
lexer ('*':cs) = TokenTimes : lexer cs
lexer ('/':cs) = TokenDiv : lexer cs
lexer ('(':cs) = TokenOB : lexer cs
lexer (')':cs) = TokenCB : lexer cs

lexNum cs = TokenInt (read num) : lexer rest
      where (num,rest) = span isDigit cs

lexVar cs =
   case span isAlpha cs of
      ("let",rest) -> TokenLet : lexer rest
      ("in",rest)  -> TokenIn : lexer rest
      (var,rest)   -> TokenVar var : lexer rest

}
```

and the Main using the parser is

```
module Main

where 
import Data.Char
import Calc

caseSensitive :: String -> String
caseSensitive = id

caseInsensitive :: String -> String
caseInsensitive = map toUpper

firstEight :: String -> String
firstEight = take 8

main :: IO ()
main = getContents >>= (\a -> print (calc (lexer a) caseInsensitive) )
```

Using the expression parser with the caseInsensitive function and the input

```
let aap = 7 in Aap + AAP
```

result in the output

```
Let "AAP" (Exp1 (Term (Factor (Int 7)))) (Exp1 (Plus (Term (Factor (Var "AAP"))) (Factor (Var "AAP"))))
```

This answers my own question partly: I would like to pass the function around using attributes and not explicitly as in this example...

Comment: Okay, now I understand you problem better. Yes, AST for `happy` needs `Show` instance. You can just add fake `Show` instances for all types of your functions and be happy with it. But probably it will be much simpler to just use _parser combinators_ instead of _parser generators_.